# Лента новостей на php (нужна помощь !)

Tags: php

```
// Выбор id залогиненного пользователя (по id буду сортироваться сообщения в ленты новостей от пользоватей на которых он подписан )

$sqlForSubscriberByLogged = "SELECT id_request_reciver FROM subscribers WHERE id_request_sender='$loggedUser->id' ";
$queryForSubscriberByLogged = $database->query($sqlForSubscriberByLogged);
$fetch_arrayForSubscriberByLogged = $database->fetch_array($queryForSubscriberByLogged);

// Здесь сортировка для ленты новостей от нужных пользователей на которых подписан залогившейся юзер.
// Фильтрация данных будет идти от id_request_reciver

$sqlForWallMessagesBySubscribers = "SELECT id_mes,id,text,sender,minute,hour,day,month,year FROM wall_messages WHERE
                                   id='$fetch_arrayForSubscriberByLogged[id_request_reciver]' ORDER BY id_mes DESC LIMIT 15";
$queryForWallMessagesBySubscribers = $database->query($sqlForWallMessagesBySubscribers);
```

Нужна помощь правильно "отфильтровать" вывод данных для ленты новостей.
То есть, я выбираю из базы данных те поля где мой id подписан на других пользователей с их id.
**Проблема в том ЧТО мне даёт только id ПОСЛЕДНЕГО ЮЗЕРА** на которого я подписался, а не выдаёт всех (то есть не все поля, а только одно), в цикле ниже просто идёт фильтрация по сообщениях. [image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Вот как получаеться.
А мне нужно что-то типа этого...
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Заранее благодарю за помощь...

Comment: Не обращайте внимания на надписи типа "имрваирмофло", это для тестирования =)

Comment: Для рыбы общепринят текст "[Lorem ipsum...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum "Вики")". До открытия этого заполнителя я тоже кошку по клаве пускал - лучший случайный текст в мире, т.к. никто и никогда не скажет что сделает кошка в следующий момент :)

Comment: @TheDoctor ахах) запомню )

Comment: Тут юзают @ для обращения: @TheDoctor

Comment: Ну и проблема-то в чем - не знаете как правильно написать запрос или что?

Comment: @u_mulder Да. Мне даёт id_request_reciver только один элемент (с индексом 3), а я подписан на два юзера. Но получаю в качестве значения последнего на кого я подписался, то есть, сообщений от юзера с id_request_reciver = 2 я не вижу.

Comment: `WHERE id IN ()`?

Comment: @u_mulder 
Я не понял что вы хотите сказать, но...
Точно знаю что проблема тут...
`$sqlForSubscriberByLogged = "SELECT id_request_reciver FROM subscribers WHERE id_request_sender='$loggedUser->id' ";
$queryForSubscriberByLogged = $database->query($sqlForSubscriberByLogged);
$fetch_arrayForSubscriberByLogged = $database->fetch_array($queryForSubscriberByLogged);`

Comment: Запрос `"SELECT id_request_reciver FROM subscribers WHERE id_request_sender='$loggedUser->id' "` возвращает сколько записей? Одну или несколько? выведите его `print_r` или `var_dump`

Comment: Второй запрос `SELECT id_mes,id,text,sender,minute,hour,day,month,year FROM ...` ищет только те записи у которых `id` равно единственному значению, не списку значений. Если вам требуется указать что `id` должен быть списком значений требуется либо `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)` или `WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 ....`. У вас же нет таких условий в запросе, откуда же взяться записям для других `id`?

Comment: @u_mulder В первом запросе возвращает только одну запись. Например если я подпишусь на юзера с id 8 то мне в качестве значения выдаст id_request_reciver = 8, а предыдущие 2,3,4,5... не выводит.

Comment: @u_mulder Во втором запросе попробовал подставить вручную в IN(2,3,4,5,6,7,8) и я удивился, работает, ну не так как нужно.. мне нужно конкретные значения подставить... как можно?

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Во-первых, как пожелание хотел бы сказать, укоротите эти длинные названия переменных. Это ни к чему, еще так можно писать в прикладном программировании, где вы к стандартному заголовку компонента дописываете свое что-то, но тут у вас просто php, так что поменяйте это).

Второе. Глядя на ваш код:

```
$sqlForSubscriberByLogged = "SELECT id_request_reciver FROM subscribers WHERE id_request_sender='$loggedUser->id' ";
$queryForSubscriberByLogged = $database->query($sqlForSubscriberByLogged);
$fetch_arrayForSubscriberByLogged = $database->fetch_array($queryForSubscriberByLogged);

// Здесь сортировка для ленты новостей от нужных пользователей на которых подписан залогившейся юзер.
// Фильтрация данных будет идти от id_request_reciver

$sqlForWallMessagesBySubscribers = "SELECT id_mes,id,text,sender,minute,hour,day,month,year FROM wall_messages WHERE
                                   id='$fetch_arrayForSubscriberByLogged[id_request_reciver]' ORDER BY id_mes DESC LIMIT 15";
$queryForWallMessagesBySubscribers = $database->query($sqlForWallMessagesBySubscribers);
```

Вы удивляетесь почему у вас указаны комментарии только одного пользователя? В первом запросе у вас стоит отбор записей, если они удовлетворяют условию такому id_request_sender='$loggedUser->id, то есть пользователя которого указали, тот и потом фетчем передается во второй запрос. Можно было бы это объединить в один запрос просто, чуть более сложный, но за то удобный и понятный. Если у вас с этим трудности, то почитайте про то, как объединять данные с нескольких таблиц, в частности конструкции WHERE, JOIN (LEFT, RIGHT, INNER), тогда все станет понятно). Удачи в работе!

Comment: Да) **На первое**. Просто программирую в Objective-C, а php я изучаю для себя, но нужно решить эту проблему, так как сайт не смогу запустить =)

**На второе**. Спасибо, я посмотрю как объединить в один запрос. Но меня заинтересовал еще способ с `IN ( )`, как предложили выше.